# Php ajax return json or html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

What is better to return to ajax: **html** data or **json**? 
I have in my php(mvc) controller `PostController` where i have metod `index`. That method return array with all users posts,comments, post likes, comment likes, etc. It is a large merged array! Somthing like on facebook wall!

All that i render in `view/home/index.php` file with `php` and with `jquery ajax` i `load` that file in specific div

But looking fb and other social network sites they return json object.

In my case if i return `json_encode` json to ajax i must loop with `each` all posts and commets.

So if i loop with `$.each` i must put to much html codes inside `$.each`.
It is not ugly and bad practice to put all that html code inside javascript looping? Or exist better solution for this loop?

Comment: I tend to prefer JSON because then I am in charge of how the data turns into the view. When you receive html short of manipulation it's basically set.

Comment: You can also send html code in json format, maybe that's an option?

Comment: This question will most likely be closed as it's a matter of opinion based on any given situation. That said, IMO you should always use JSON unless HTML has some specific client-side benefit.

Comment: So is better to use `JSON` than? And is not bad practice to put large `HTML` inside looping with `$.each` ?

Comment: I found solution. Its okay to return `JSON` but better to use some `jQuery Template` for this

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the data. If you use the data as a presentation of data on which you will not perform any calculation, you might use HTML. That way you can easily replace a part of your website with javascript, without having to deal with structuring your data.

However, If you want to perform calculations on the data or if you want to use only parts of the data on different places, JSON is the way to go.

Please note that this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can define what type of data do you want like below

Datatype:json or datatype:html in jquery ajax